# Android NDK 2020 C code - How to enable release mode with all optimizations

Tags: android, c++, optimization, android-ndk, release

[image]

I see that people do this by changing their Android.mk and Application.mk files. However, I cannot find the file in my project at all. What I wish to do is to optimize the code as much as possible (in Visual Studio, Release mode can be 10x faster than Debug mode). How can I do this in android NDK ?

Thank you.

```
APP_OPTIM := release
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=0
-DNDEBUG
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O2
```

Comment: You're building your native code with CMake, not ndkBuild, so there won't be any Android.mk or Application.mk. Your native build settings go into CMakeLists.txt and app/build.gradle. Having said that, unless you've done something strange, the native code should automatically be built in release mode (with optimizations on) if you build your app in release mode.

Comment: I used the example project in android studio which has the word NDK, so I thought is ndkBuild. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to specify some options manually only in release configuration, append cppFlags to the relevant section in app/build.gradle as follows.

```
android {

    :

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags += "-O2 -DNDEBUG"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    :
}
```

Comment: Does "-DNDEBUG" means #define notdebug ? I couldn't find this command on google

Comment: it works but the speed is still the same :\ I guess a Snapdragon 821 is just 10 times slower than i7 laptop at single core

Comment: NDEBUG is a flag to notify code that it's non-debug builds. But it might not take any effects even if you add it explicitly, because it's automatically defined by IDE. As @Michael indicates above, almost all optimizations are to be applied by default in release builds. Confirm all the options actually being applied by inspecting the file app/.cxx/cmake/release/*/build_command.txt. ...Maybe, smartphone can never have processing speed comparable to that on PC whatever optimization is to be applied.